# Вопросительные местоимения в родительном падеже

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов

Когда вопросительное местоимение "кого" используется в значении "чей" ("чья", "чьё", "чьи") и в чём разница между "чей" и "кого" в этом контексте?

Comment: _"...в этом контексте?"_ === А контекст-то где?

Comment: Вероятно, = "в контексте первой части вопроса".

Comment: У Автора своё мнение есть?

Comment: @slava1947 в контексте "чей" напр.: Это кого книга? (Это чья книга?)

Comment: @shampar Своё мнение довольно смутное, иначе бы не спрашивал. Приходится объяснять грамматику русского иностранцам, был проставлен в тупик этим вопросом

Answer (score 2):

Притяжательное местоимение "чей" требует замены на "кого" в уточняющих вопросах: а) для определения падежных окончаний, б) в случаях, когда принадлежность условна и "чей" не подходит, и в) в вопросах, выражающих недоумение. 
В большинстве других случаев такая замена стилистически не оправдывается.

```
- Забыл я фамилию учёного - закон кого это? 
- Менделеева-Клапейрона. 

- Склероз, лошадиная фамилия... лошадь кого это? 
- Пржевальского.

- Чья это статья?
- Монгольского космонавта Жугдердамедийна Гуррагчи.
- Кого?!
```

Comment: Спасибо... нигде не мог найти вразумительный ответ на этот вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Разница, похоже в порядке слов.

"Чей/чья/чьё" (и прилагательные, образованные от них) ставятся чаще всего перед определяемым словом.  "Кого/чего" (и существительные, образованные таким образом), *следуют* за определяемым словом:

> **Машина** машина (чья?)
>   Машина **Маши** (кого?)

Конечно, можно порядок и поменять, в русском-таки строгости большой нет, но натуральный порядок (например, определение + определяемое слово) существует.